# Why is this equivalence only for integers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic, real-numbers

I read about the following rule:

> $m < n$ is equivalent to $m + 1 \leq n$, for $m, n \in \mathbb Z$

Why is it only for integers though? I can't think of a counter example e.g. for real numbers.

Comment: What non-integer numbers (e.g. real non-integers) have you thought about?

Comment: How about $0.5<1\to1.5\leq1$?

Comment: Many examples can be provided. Like if we take $m$ as the square root of $2$ and $n$ as 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This holds for subsets of real numbers where the gap of consecutive numbers is at least $1$ and the gap doesn't even have to be uniform.

For example, it holds even for $m, n \in  \mathbb{Z}+\frac12$, which is technically just a translation of the integers.

If $m < n$, then since we know the  gap is at least $1$, we know that $m+1$ would not exceed $n$.

Comment: What is the meaning of "structures"? Are integers, real etc called formally structures?

Comment: I was being too casual. I have edited it to subset of real number where the gap of consecutive numbers is at least $1$.

Comment: We do know that $m + 1$ will not exceed $n$ but why we use $<=$? I mean $2 < 18$ but does that mean that we can have $2 + 1 <= 18$?

Comment: Although the reverse makes sense. I.e. if $m + 1 <= n$ then $m < n$

Comment: $2+1 \le 18$ is a true statement, it means $3 < 18$ or $3 = 18$. Even though $3 =18$ is false, $3<18$ is true. For an "or" statement to be true, we just need one of them to be true. $17 < 18$ and we have $18 \le 18$ which means $18 < 18$ or $18 = 18$.

Comment: When I see the equivalence $<$ is equivalent to $+1≤$ my confusion is that for the case $2 < 18$ how can we claim that $3<=18$? I guess it is because of the $<$ of the statement that is `true` as you explained? I mean why not claim then that $m < n$ is equivalent to $m <=n$ in the first place?

Comment: because it is not true, consider $18 < 18$ is not true but $18 \le 18$ is true.